# How to create an array of linear gradient brushes in xaml using static resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to create an array of gradient brushes in xaml but I would like to point each array element back to a static resource that is the gradient brush. So, far I've been unable to achieve this. Can someone provide guidance on how I might accomplish this?

I want to add them to an x:Array but point to the resource rather than having to re-define the brushes as I've had to do here. I use the brushes in several places in addition to an array of them so I only want to define the brushes once.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OrangeLinearGradientBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFF7941D" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFF26522" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RedLinearGradientBrush" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#F26263" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#B80303" />
</LinearGradientBrush>

<x:Array x:Key="BrushArray" Type="LinearGradientBrush">
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FFF7941D" />
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FFF26522" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#F26263" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#B80303" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
</x:Array>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use StaticResourceExtensions:

```
<x:Array x:Key="BrushArray" Type="LinearGradientBrush">
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="OrangeLinearGradientBrush"/>
    <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="RedLinearGradientBrush"/>
</x:Array>
```